# How do I stop memory issue caused by baloo_file_extractor?

Tags: kde, dolphin

I using Arch Linux with XFCE/XFWM4.
The default FM is very lightweight thunar, but I installed dolphin for some more functionality.

I was studying about large files and creating some 2 gigs of files on my system. I suddenly saw my system is going wild where `baloo_file_extractor` uses 3.1 GiB RAM! I suddenly killed it.

But every time I create a big file, I see `baloo_file_extractor` uses up all of my RAM and start consuming swap again and again.

On the other hand, I haven't used dolphin for weeks now. Why does it daemonize baloo when dolphin is not in use?

Apart from uninstalling `baloo`, `baloo_widgets` and `dolphin` file manager, is there any other way to prevent that from happening again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `balooctl disable`. That'll turn off baloo and you won't need to uninstall anything.